# Need help on automating Active Directory Groups

Tags: active-directory

I have a requirement  and I am not sure if this is possible or not. so just wanted to get the suggestions before I start with it.

I have few AD groups which I am maintaining manually like adding, removing members.   Now if a member leaves the team or changes his supervisor manager , he needs to removed from the particular AD group.

Is it possible to automate this thru scripting. ?

Comment: What changes in AD when those events happen? Also, are you only talking about distribution lists (with Exchange?), or security groups too?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a group to add or remove members is easily done in many different languages. In every case, you need appropriate business logic to say "when team changes from X, remove from group Y" or "when manager changes to A, add to group B".

The tricky bit is identifying when the change needs to be made. There are many ways to do this.

1. Hook the process that changes the info in the first place -- if the team and manager are input through an HR system or custom web site, the data input source can be used to create an event. This can be adding a web call to an existing web form, creating a custom view of the HR data table, etc.
2. If changes are made in AD directly, Active Directory Domain Services [supports change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/change-notifications-in-active-directory-domain-services) -- this can add significant load to the system, so may or may not be reasonable depending on the number of objects and frequency of changes.
3. If the change does not need to be immediate, a batch approach may be viable and you can use an LDAP filter to identify memberships that need to change rather than trigger events directly from changes.

I use the third method. There's little directory impact and it does not require changes be made outside of AD. The drawback is that the group change isn't immediate. Since we're not talking about terminated accounts (who wouldn't be able to access the system anyway), I trust people who are still employed by the company not to abuse their access for the time they're still in the group (and, honestly, it's not like the reporting change gets registered immediately where I work -- HR has to input the change, then the change gets fed into an identity management platform, *then* the new info makes it into AD. I know people who have been in a new position for a week or two before the reporting change was processed through HR. My extra six hours or so where the user is in a group aren't a huge deal).

If members of a group should all report to a set of managers and/or have a specific department value, a filter like:

```
(&(memberOf=cn=mygroup,ou=specialgroups,dc=company,dc=gTLD)(!((|(manager=dn=Bob,ou=employees,dc=company,dc=com)(department=Engineering)))))
```

will identify anyone who is a member of MyGroup that does not report to Bob or work in the Engineering department - modify the group to remove those members.

Adjust the filter to require both the manager and team values be something specific, have a list of valid managers, etc. You can reverse the query as well to identify anyone who *is* in the Engineering department or reports to Bob but is not a member of the group:

```
(&(!(memberOf=cn=mygroup,ou=specialgroups,dc=company,dc=gTLD))((|(manager=dn=Bob,ou=employees,dc=company,dc=com)(department=Engineering))))
```

Modify the group to add those users as members.

I've stored the group membership qualification filter on an attribute of the group itself -- primarily so I wouldn't need to recompile my code whenever the "rule" changes. There's then a web front end that allows the individuals listed in the filter to add/remove managers and departments to the qualification list. That may be overkill if your organization is fairly static, but I didn't want to deal with a bunch of "oh, now the people who report to Frank should be in here too" calls.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there can be several ways to automate this.

Probably the simplest way to do that is have a scheduled task that will periodically run through your users, check if the user's team, supervisor or any other parameter that can change corresponds to the current group membership, if not, the task needs to remove the user from the groups he or she no longer needs to be a member of.

Another way you can do that is with some third-party software. The benefits of using that approach is that once you introduce changes (e.g. change the user's manager), all the other actions are executed instantly, so you don't need to wait for the Scheduled Task to act.

Here's an example with Adaxes, a solution that we have. There are other solutions as well, but this one shows and explains the approach really well. It allows you to have an automation rule that's triggered after a user is updated and if the correct conditions are met (e.g. the Manager property is changed), then it can automatically remove a user from a group.

Here's a tutorial that explains how you can automate group membership using condition-based rules in more details: https://www.adaxes.com/tutorials_AutomatingDailyTasks_AddUsersToGroupsByDepartment.htm